# Testing the significance of two differences

Tags: r, statistical-significance, t-test

I have a number of data points, which result in the array of box plots similar to the below.
[image]

For each diagnosis, I tested two different times, P1/P3, in two different conditions, "all" and "subset". I would like to test whether the *difference between the difference between P1 and P3* is significant for each metric, for each diagnosis. Is there a method to test the significance of two *differences*?

Comment: If the P1 and P3 times are recorded per-individual, it should be straightforward: generate the differences by subtraction and using a two-group t-test (if normally distributed) / median test (if not). Someone with more theory may contradict me!

Comment: If you are going to use any test 10 different times,  you might want to consider the [Bonferroni correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction)

Comment: That's certainly a good point. In my mind I was thinking I could avoid it, but you're right, I probably need to still use it.